# VK_API Как запостить картинку на стену? python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Имеется ссылка на загрузку фотографии в переменной `postUrlHttp`(получен  методом photos.getWallUploadServer) и имеется url фотографии со стороннего сайта в переменной `picUrl`. Как запостить фото на стену?

Answer (score 0):

в примере использована библиотека `vk_api`

```py
url = vk.photos.getMarketUploadServer(**p_params)['upload_url'] # это как я понимаю у Вас уже сделано
img = requests.get('your_img_url') # Получаем изображение по ссылке
file = {
        'file': img.content # Создаем параметр file (как написано где-то в инструкции на VK)
    }
    response = requests.post(url, files=file) # Загружаем изображение на сервер и получаем параметры этого изображения для публикации
    payloads = response.json() # Собственно здесь будут параметры

photo = vk.photos.saveMarketPhoto(
        group_id=classtrucks_id,
        **payloads
    )[0] # сохраняем на сервере VK
....
# и далее при создании какого либо сообщения (в моем случае была карточка товара) используем как-то так
'main_photo_id': photo['id'],
```

Comment: Не загружает фото все равно, возвращает параметр photo пустым

Comment: @Flywalk Вышеприведенеый спсоб используется для загрузки фото в карточку магазина. Покурите мануалы, возможно что для публикации на стену есть нюансы